# Sort the order of Soundcloud Custom Player playlists

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I am using the soundcloud custom player to pull in favorites. my question is how do i sort by date favorited, not by date uploaded which is the default in the minimal demo?

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player

the script i'm working off of is here: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js

in my implementation i built the player using:

```
<div class="post faves">
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/mr-tunes/favorites" class="sc-player"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: hey its already giving by sort date favorited

Comment: on my live site http://mrtunes.ca/ it's going by alphabetical though. sorry not alphabetical, something stranger than that hah.

Comment: it's sorting by date the track was uploaded. not the date it was favourited. sorry it took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Soundcloud does not provide ways of sorting the tracks through their API, only to filter them.
The API does not provide a parameter for when the track was set as favorite by the user.

By default it should sort by time when it was set as favorite, and you could reverse this by adding each track into an array and run array.reverse() on it.

For sorting alphabetically or by any other parameter provided by the API you can use the same method, putting the parameters into an array and using .sort() and / or .reverse()